# Python jquery web game

Tags: jquery, python, mongodb, web, web.py

I'm trying to develop a web based text strategy game. The idea includes being in space, seeing a radar screen, and moving around, attacking other players, mining planets and so on.

Current technologies i've tried are:

- Python for the server side game engine/database queries
- Mongodb for hosting the database
- Web.py for serving the web pages.
- Jquery for the interface on the website.
- HTML5 W/canvas for displaying the radar which will just be a simple query of what is near my current position.

Current development stage:

Python:

I've written a text based command line game that walks through some of the scanning and moving of the player's objects around the database.

Mongodb:

The database is set up and running great. I'm able to manipulate objects and query objects.

web.py:

Currently supports 'localhost:8080('/', '/register', '/game') When you arrive, it has a very simple login box that uses no real authentication but a simple db.users.find({}) to validate the user. I will expand on this later, but for simple testing with friends I wasn't too worried about security just yet. If they enter the wrong values, it rolls over to /register where they can create an account. Then it drops them into /game where i'm able to pull the username from the form('name') and print a simple Hello %name.

Jquery:

Able to execute jquery scripts to manipulate divs and what not.

HTML5:

No real development yet, but HTML is my strongest point so i'm not worried about that just yet.

Challenges:

The real road block I've hit is trying to figure out how to feed the user a *.html page with jquery post'ing to my back end python scripts to perform queries or updates on the database or execute some code for battles and what not.

I've been reading up on all the different technologies and frameworks but I haven't really found anything that fits exactly what I need, or my lack of experience prevents me from understanding how to implement it.

I'm wondering is there an easy way to write a jquery(post) that will post data into python so the functions i've written can perform queries or updates based on the jquery(post) and return the data the user is requesting

I watched a youtube tutorial for posting to php and it looked incredibly easy, but anytime I search for post to python, I get very few results and almost all procrlaiming their framework is best for that. I'm almost wondering if I shouldn't just switch to php.

Can you guys point me in the right direction? Do I need to scrap the web.py and switch to ajax and mod_python?

Should I just buckel down and read through django's documentation thoroughly?

I'm going to be on really slow internet this weekend and was hoping that I could find the right direction to reaserch in so when I return to my place on Saturday I can start working on the web portion of the strategy game.

code examples:

web.py Script:

```
import web
from web import form
import pymongo

db = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017).bbarnes_test
render = web.template.render('templates/')
urls = (
  '/', 'index',
  '/register', 'register',
  '/game', 'game')

app = web.application(urls, globals(), True)

login = form.Form(
    form.Textbox("Username",
                form.notnull),
    form.Password("Password",
        form.notnull))


class index:
    def GET(self):
        form = login()
        return render.formtest(form)

    def POST(self):
        form = login()
        if not form.validates():
            return render.formtest(form)
        else:
                        uname = db.users.find_one({'name' : form.d.Username, 'pw' : form.d.Password})

                        if uname != None:
                                return render.game(uname['name'])
                        else:
                                raise web.seeother('/register')

class register:
        def GET(self):
                form = login()
                return render.register(form)

        def POST(self):
                form = login()
                if not form.validates():
                        return render.register(form)
                else:
                        db.users.insert({'name' : form.d.Username, 'pw' : form.d.Password})
                uname = db.users.find_one({'name' : form.d.Username})
                raise web.seeother('/')


class game:
        def GET(self):
                return render.game(form)

if __name__=="__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
~
```

game.html

```
$def with(uname)
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
J = jQuery;
J(document).ready(function(){
        J("p").click(function(){
                J(this).hide();
        });
});



</script>

<title>The Game</title>
</head


<body>
<p> This is a test of jQuery.</p>
<p> Welcome to the game $uname</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'll try to say this without sounding condescending. :-) This is way too much for a post. Try to boil down your "main problem" into a small, reproduceable example. This makes it much easier for us to focus on your actual problem. If more context is required, we'll ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of it incorrectly if you're thinking about your Python scripts being separate from your web infrastructure.  When you're talking about doing HTTP calls like POST to a web application in order to manipulate data in a database--that's a web service.  Most of my experience is with Pyramid + Cornice and Django + Piston (ugh), but web.py is fairly capable and should be able to do this.  [This blog post](http://johnpaulett.com/2008/09/20/getting-restful-with-webpy/) is old, but looks promising. You'll also have more luck searching for "RESTful web services python" or something similar.